# Postgresql: JSONB Data Type column not null error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to alter one column which has JSONB data type in postgresql.

```
ALTER TABLE my_schema_name."my_table_name" ALTER COLUMN "my_column_name" SET NOT NULL;
```

It is giving me below error.

```
SQL Error [23502]: ERROR: column "my_column_name" contains null values
```

Note: columns are added newly and there is no data in these columns.

Comment: Well, you need to update the existing NULL values to something that is not null.

Comment: the column contains some NULL cells, so it can not be set as not-null. first fill the NULLs with something, then retry your ALTER command.

Comment: I have added column freshly and there is no value in table for this column

Comment: What is the result of `select count(*) from my_schema_name."my_table_name" where "my_column_name" is null;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is something I have updated table with default value and then alter the column with Not null.